# How does the Docker SDK for Python’s ‘exec_run’ work with Cassandra CQLSH

Tags: python, docker, cqlsh

I am trying to run `cqlsh` using the Docker SDK for python but whenever I run it doesn't provide any output.

`container.exec_run('cqlsh', stdin=True, tty=True)` equivalent to `docker exec -it cassandra cqlsh`.

Comment: Please confirm what version of the SDK you are using.

Comment: I am using python package docker==4.3.0